# Queries with inner object are not cached in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, caching

I have found, that the a very simple queries, like

```
        Session s = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        List<Mod> list = s.createQuery("from Mod m where m.modNameShort=:modName")
                .setParameter("modName", modName)
                .setCacheable(true)
                .list();
```

are cached well.

But cache is not working for one-to-many selections, like this:

```
List<ModVersion> list = s.createQuery("select m.modsVersionses from Mod m")
                .setCacheable(true)
                .list();
```

It still makes requests to DB on second and next calls.

I have

```
        props.setProperty("hibernate.cache.provider_class", "org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider");
        props.setProperty("hibernate.cache.region.factory_class", "org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory");
        props.setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache", "true");
        props.setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_query_cache", "true");
        factoryBean.setHibernateProperties(props);
```

, and the Mod object looks like

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "mods", catalog = "artfunpw")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.TRANSACTIONAL)
public class Mod implements java.io.Serializable {
***
 @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "mods") 
    @OrderBy("ReleaseDate desc")
    public Set<ModVersion> getModsVersionses() {
        return this.modsVersionses;
    }
***
```

The ModVersion object looks like

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "mods_versions", catalog = "artfunpw", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "VersionNumber"))
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.TRANSACTIONAL)
public class ModVersion implements java.io.Serializable {
```

How to enable caching for such one-to-many queries?

Thank you!

Comment: Try adding `@Cache` annotation on the `OneToMany`  method I.e., `getModsVersionses`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible, my question is duplicate.

I found answer here [Using hibernate 2nd level cache or query cache for lazy fetch queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10350794/using-hibernate-2nd-level-cache-or-query-cache-for-lazy-fetch-queries) and http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#performance-cache-mapping

I should to add `@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)` :

```
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "mods", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})  
    @OrderBy("ReleaseDate desc")
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE) 
    public Set<ModVersion> getModsVersionses() {
        return this.modsVersionses;
    }
```